How to find the emptiest part of a picture?
Suppose I have this graph of points:

I am trying to find out the most crowded and most emptiest part of this picture.

Idea 1: The first thing I thought of was to make a density map of the plot and identify high and low density regions using the exponential decay kernel:

For any point $(x,y)$ in the 100×100 grid, the density $D(x,y)$ is calculated as:
$$ D(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{-d_i/b} $$
where:

$n$ is the number of colored points
$b$ is the bandwidth parameter (set to 5)
$d_i$ is the Euclidean distance from $(x,y)$ to each colored point $(x_i,y_i)$:
$$ d_i = \sqrt{(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2} $$

Then for selecting new points, the probability $P(x,y)$ of selecting any uncolored point is:
For density-avoiding (low-density seeking):
$$ P(x,y) = \frac{1}{D(x,y) + 0.1} \cdot \frac{1}{Z_1} $$
For density-seeking (high-density seeking):
$$ P(x,y) = (D(x,y) + 0.1) \cdot \frac{1}{Z_2} $$
where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are normalization constants that make the probabilities sum to 1 (where $U$ is the set of all uncolored points):
$$ Z_1 = \sum_{(x,y) \in U} \frac{1}{D(x,y) + 0.1} $$
$$ Z_2 = \sum_{(x,y) \in U} (D(x,y) + 0.1) $$
I made a visual below for the highest and lowest density areas of this photo:

This seems to have capture the empty spaces well.

Idea 2: I tried a second way in which the median distance between each empty point is calculated relative to ALL other non-empty points:


This did not appear to work well, so I tried to adjust the radius value:

It seems like there is a sweet spot between radius=15 and radius =20 that captures this well.
In general, is there something else I can do to mathematically identify the emptiest regions of this picture?


Note: Computer code (R) is available in case anyone is interested

Here is the R code to generate the data for this problem:
library(dplyr)

grid_size <- 100
total_points <- grid_size * grid_size
points_to_color <- 100

grid_data <- expand.grid(
    x = 1:grid_size,
    y = 1:grid_size
) %>%
    mutate(
        colored = row_number() %in% sample(1:total_points, points_to_color)
    )

Here is the Python code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

grid_size = 100
total_points = grid_size * grid_size
points_to_color = 100

grid_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.repeat(np.arange(1, grid_size + 1), grid_size),
    'y': np.tile(np.arange(1, grid_size + 1), grid_size)
})

colored_indices = np.random.choice(total_points, points_to_color, replace=False)
grid_data['colored'] = grid_data.index.isin(colored_indices)

print(grid_data)


I'm not an expert, so don't cite me on this: But there is this tool of (multi-parameter) persistent homology, that manages to identify dense (or rather connected) areas of a point cloud. It is based, essentially, on the approach of the answer given by @vallev, i.e. by blowing up balls centered at the points.

At every point indicated, expand a ball using your preferred metric. Count the amount of empty space and stop when satisfied.
Formally, this is taking the Minkowski sum of your set with a ball of a given radius $ S \oplus B_r=\left\{x+y: x \in S, y \in B_r\right\}$
Here is your picture expanded pointwise with the taxicab metric:

And with the Euclidean metric

I used an image editing tool ( repeatedly copying and moving layers NSEW for the first one, and repeating ink and contrast effects for the second one) to illustrate but code could be easily made for the general task. *
If you iterate this process you could also assign a "farness" value $z$ to each pixel based on the radius it first got covered by. Essentially a function $f(x,y)=z$ you could run gradient algorithms in (the solution need not be unique).

This algorithm also has another nice application. If you make the balls see-through (keeping only the boundary) and wait until they all intersect, the point at which all boundaries intersect is the point that minimizes the distance to the sum of all of the other points (or sets, which are collections of points anyways). You can even include a restriction for that point to be in a given area if you want. I believe a formal treatment would be covered by a branch of mathematics called variational analysis.
I don't know what the expansion algorithm is called but I remember seeing it on a slide on some convex optimization research by a professor.
Finally, you could do it the other way due to symmetry. Expand a ball on each empty spot and record the highest radius that does not include any point of your set. I'm not sure which is more efficient and won't bother proving the equivalence.
*Fun fact: you can also do numerical integration by counting colored pixels with an image editing tool.

Wow! I never thought this problem was so complicated! Thank you so much!

Would you like the computer code (e.g. R, Python) to generate the original picture in my question? It would be interesting to compare algorithms and see the results

The idea itself is simple but it's the theory that is complicated because of mathematical rigour and because the results extend to more kinds of functions and topologies/spaces that may not be as nice. I only remember that advances in those fields make chunks of our digital technology more efficient, but I do not enough to point out exactly how. There is an option to embed code in the post if you feel like it would help but it may make it too long.

I'll also point out that if an inexact answer is good enough, you could look at Monte Carlo type algorithms. Simply take points at random and choose the optimal one. It is much less computationally expensive, but it is inexact and nonexhaustive.

I have posted the data for this problem

Can you please go over again how Monte Carlo type algorithms could be used for this problem?

Monte Carlo is used for example in numerical integration, you can see a gif here in the wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method where they use it to calculate area. Of course, if you care about distance instead you can also estimate that.
